# Moving a node a bit

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following code instructs TikZ to draw an obtuse triangle. Except for the placement of the letter "C" in the diagram, the diagram is drawn correctly.  I want to move the letter "C" downwards a little more so that it is not on the triangle.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (110:4.5) coordinate (A) (-30:3) coordinate (B) (0:0) coordinate (C);
\draw (A)
-- (B) node [at start, above left]{$A$} node [midway, right]{$c$}
-- (C) node [at start, right]{$B$} node [midway, below] {$a$}
-- (A) node [at start, below, left]{$C$} node [midway, left]  {$b$} -- cycle;
\coordinate (P) at ($(B)!(A)!(C)$);
\draw[dashed] (A) -- (P) node [below, left]{$P$} node [midway, left]{$h$} -- (C);
\draw[dashed] (P) -- node [midway, below]{$x$}(C);
\draw[|<->|] ($(B)!7mm!90:(P)$)--node[fill=white,sloped] {$a + x$} ($(P)!7mm!-90:(B)$);
\draw pic[draw, angle radius=2mm,"$\theta$",angle eccentricity=2] {angle = B--C--A};
\tkzMarkRightAngle(A,P,C);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10):

Use the key `yshift=`:

[image: output]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (110:4.5) coordinate (A) (-30:3) coordinate (B) (0:0) coordinate (C);
\draw (A)
-- (B) node [at start, above left]{$A$} node [midway, right]{$c$}
-- (C) node [at start, right]{$B$} node [midway, below] {$a$}
-- (A) node [at start, below, left, yshift=-2mm]{$C$} node [midway, left]  {$b$} -- cycle;
\coordinate (P) at ($(B)!(A)!(C)$);
\draw[dashed] (A) -- (P) node [below, left]{$P$} node [midway, left]{$h$} -- (C);
\draw[dashed] (P) -- node [midway, below]{$x$}(C);
\draw[|<->|] ($(B)!7mm!90:(P)$)--node[fill=white,sloped] {$a + x$} ($(P)!7mm!-90:(B)$);
\draw pic[draw, angle radius=2mm,"$\theta$",angle eccentricity=2] {angle = B--C--A};
\tkzMarkRightAngle(A,P,C);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are giving the key `below,left` which `tikz` takes only as `left` (the latest key). It should be `below left` without `,` in the middle. So

```
node [at start, below left]{$C$}
```

would give you

[image]

You can also use just `below` (which is better than `left`). If you want absolute control, you may use

```
below left=below length and left length
```

like

```
below left=0mm and -1mm
```

Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (110:4.5) coordinate (A) (-30:3) coordinate (B) (0:0) coordinate (C);
\draw (A)
-- (B) node [at start, above left]{$A$} node [midway, right]{$c$}
-- (C) node [at start, right]{$B$} node [midway, below] {$a$}
-- (A) node [at start, below left=0mm and -1mm]{$C$} node [midway, left]  {$b$} -- cycle;
\coordinate (P) at ($(B)!(A)!(C)$);
\draw[dashed] (A) -- (P) node [below, left]{$P$} node [midway, left]{$h$} -- (C);
\draw[dashed] (P) -- node [midway, below]{$x$}(C);
\draw[|<->|] ($(B)!7mm!90:(P)$)--node[fill=white,sloped] {$a + x$} ($(P)!7mm!-90:(B)$);
\draw pic[draw, angle radius=2mm,"$\theta$",angle eccentricity=2] {angle = B--C--A};
\tkzMarkRightAngle(A,P,C);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Using "below left" is fine.  Thanks. Why doesn't TikZ compile the optional command "left below"? Is "below below left" an option?

Comment: @user60254 `left below` and `below below left` are not defined and hence are not possible.